# How can I connect the ireport to java swing project in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

So, I am confused in how to use ireport in the netbeans? and also want to know more about its programmatic method ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is too general of a question for this site. It's designed for specific programming questions regarding work that has already been done.

Comment: Do you know anything about it .????!!

Comment: If you want to know something about it, I am guessing there must be plenty of online resources you could find just by googling.

Comment: Oh , Thanks Matt, How can I repay you from this information.. Thank u very much ....!!!